# Did Trump say “going loco”?

Tags: quotes, donald-trump

The following [site](https://www.vox.com/policy-and-politics/2018/10/11/17963476/donald-trump-fed-loco-crazy) as well as other websites state that President Trump used the expression “going loco” referring to the Federal Reserve Bank and their interest rate policy.

> “The problem I have is with the Fed,” he told Fox’s Shannon Bream, pushing back on allegations that trade tensions with China were roiling financial markets. “The Fed is going wild. They’re raising rates and it’s ridiculous.”
>
> Delving further into the nuances of monetary policy, he added that “the Fed is going loco.”

I couldn’t  find any video in which the President  uses such an expression. Did he say it?

Comment: Not really an unusual expression, although possibly one that is less common these days. From Spanish 'loco' meaning mad. Perhaps most famously used in the song "Loco in  Acapulco" by the Four Tops in 1988.

Comment: @PhillS - yes, but definately a rare expression https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going+loco%2C+going+crazy&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoing%20loco%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoing%20crazy%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @user070221 - Any US-raised boy of his age would be quite familiar with "loco" from TV westerns.

Comment: This isn't really a strange thing for any American to say. It's not speaking Spanish, as a phrase it's part of American English. It's not the least bit scandalous.

Comment: Trump knows all the best words.

Comment: Is there a reason to be skeptical that he said this? He says lots of things, as do thousands of other politicians around the world. Sometimes they use expressions you might not hear very often, but ... so what? If the answer was no, what difference would it make to the quote? It's very different from when someone says something offensive, and is called out on it; then, it *matters* what the words used were.

Comment: @IMSoP because it is an unusual or ,as observed, obsolete expression, not to mention the fact he is referring to the FED. Did I upset anybody for asking this? Should I not be skeptical about what the papers say. What’s the problem?

Comment: I'm struggling to see the "notable claim" here.  I'm only a few years younger than Trump and would not perceive anything strange about the use of "loco" in this context.  Any boy who watched TV westerns in the 50s and 60s would know the term.

Comment: @user070221 I'm not upset, just bemused. By all means, be skeptical, but this seems an odd detail to spend energy examining. What would be someone's motive in reporting that he said this if he didn't? It seems no more important than what colour shirt he was wearing at the time, unless the entire speech was fabricated.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Heck, I wasn't raised in USA and I know the term.

Comment: @IMSoP are you saying my question id off topic?

Comment: @IMSoP I will ask on meta about your issues

Comment: @user070221: "it is an unusual or obsolete expression", are you actually surprised that a person born in 1946 is using odd and outdated expressions?

Comment: @Giter - I am not surprised, I just asked if he really used that expression. And if older Americans are familiar with it, I think  younger generations are not.

Comment: @user070221 I disagree with those calling it an "odd and outdated expression". I'm an American in my early twenties and I'm familiar with the word. In any case, if you have a question about the currentness or popularity of a word you know where to ask, since the comments section here isn't really the place to be discussing this.

Comment: @Laurel - I didn’t start the discussion about the popularity of the expression. I was just wondering if Trump actually used the expression referring to the FED.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Why westerns? I am familiar with the term and it was used a lot in my childhood, but I never attached that to any western show/movie context.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - I'm thinking it was a favorite term of Andy Devine's.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Okay. By time I was a kid, in the 70s, it had migrated to common use for "crazy".

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - It meant "crazy" in the 50s too.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - didn't mean otherwise, just that we didn't realize it had come from a popular western-based TV show, originally. I learned something new!

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - I can't say that Andy Devine introduced the term, but it was a common term in kiddie westerns of the 50s and 60s.

Comment: The *OED* has "loco" meaning "insane" in 1852.  They do say this usage was originally American slang, from Spanish.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**He did**, during a call to Fox News on Wednesday (October 10) evening. See e.g. [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPi9QvGBGog&feature=youtu.be&t=47)
at 0:46.

> The FED is going *loco*, and there's no reason for them to do it, and I'm not happy about it.

You can also see this on [this other video (official Fox News channel)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GAcOkzMuFY&feature=youtu.be&t=1218) at approximately 20:18.